# Implementing AdMob for testing to my app

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I am trying to test the adMob on my app. I follow the steps from https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start  and everything looks good except this part:

It says on the site: "add the PlaceHolder fragment in the RelativeLayout, and include the AdFragment below the PlaceHolder fragment:"

```
<fragment   android:name="com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample.MyActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/adFragment" />

<fragment
            android:id="@+id/adFragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample.MyActivity$AdFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

when I add this part to my xml, this part below has a red color and it says "cannot resolve symbol"

```
.example.bannerexample.MyActivity$PlaceholderFragment
```

There is no explanation about that, I think I have to change some part of this line according to my app but which part?

Or somthing else that I missed?

**Update:**

logcat says that:

```
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample.MyActivity$PlaceholderFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

**Update 2:**

I have solved this problem by changing the full line with "com.myc.myapp.myactivity$PlaceholderFragment"

nothing appears on the ad layout, just empty.

**Update 3:**

I added an adListener and I get the toast from onAdLoaded function. But there is nothing on the screen except my other layouts. The Layout that I used for ad is empty.

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdOpened() {
                    // Save app state before going to the ad overlay.
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
                    msg = errorCode +"";
                    Toast.makeText(c, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    super.onAdLoaded();
                    msg = "done";
                    Toast.makeText(c, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

**Update 4:**

my class where I wanted to show the add:

```
public class OyunAna extends ActionBarActivity {
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
            public PlaceholderFragment() {
            }
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }

        }
        public static class AdFragment extends Fragment {

            private AdView mAdView;

            public AdFragment() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
                super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

                // Gets the ad view defined in layout/ad_fragment.xml with ad unit ID set in
                // values/strings.xml.
                mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);

                // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
                // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
                // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                        .addTestDevice("my device id goes here")
                        .build();

                // Start loading the ad in the background.
                mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
                mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdOpened() {
                        // Save app state before going to the ad overlay.
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                        super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
                        msg = errorCode +"";
                        Toast.makeText(c, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        super.onAdLoaded();
                        msg = "done";
                        Toast.makeText(c, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ad, container, false);
            }

            /** Called when leaving the activity */
            @Override
            public void onPause() {
                if (mAdView != null) {
                    mAdView.pause();
                }
                super.onPause();
            }

            /** Called when returning to the activity */
            @Override
            public void onResume() {
                super.onResume();
                if (mAdView != null) {
                    mAdView.resume();
                }
            }

            /** Called before the activity is destroyed */
            @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
                if (mAdView != null) {
                    mAdView.destroy();
                }
                super.onDestroy();
            }

        }
```

fragment_ad:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

my activity layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.cdev.colormatch.OyunAna"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1">

        <fragment
               android:name="com.cdev.colormatch.OyunAna$PlaceholderFragment"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_above="@+id/adFragment" />

           <fragment
               android:id="@+id/adFragment"
               android:name="com.cdev.colormatch.OyunAna$AdFragment"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>
.
.
.
.
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want test ads then see:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/banner#test_ads

Otherwise look at your logs to make sure the ad request is being sent and what the response is.

Comment: I rebuilt everything according to your link but still get nothing. Please see my third update on the question.

Comment: What do your logs say? Show the code where you creatre the AdView and load the ad.

Comment: I have added an update about the codes.  I cant see anything related to ads, google play services or connection problems on my log. And as I said "done" msg appears with the toast, from onAdLoaded();

Comment: Also It shows "Ads by Google" on the fragment_ad layout, on the preview of the layout, but in my main layout, I see "<fragment/>"

Comment: Logcat ALWAYS contains details when an AdRequest is made and response is received.